# Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when using ros3djs and roslibjs in ROS web interface

Tags: websocket, ros, roslibjs

I am making a ros-web interface. For this I am using the ros3djs and roslibjs. Following the tutorials from the official ros website, I made the html page which uses the scripts link and displays the map data which is being published on /map topic. I am not getting any map output and on checking my console I am seeing this error.

```
GET https://static.robotwebtools.org/threejs/current/three.min.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
   
GET https://static.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
     
GET https://static.robotwebtools.org/ros3djs/current/ros3d.min.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I am using the exact script links as in the tutorial;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.robotwebtools.org/threejs/current/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.robotwebtools.org/ros3djs/current/ros3d.min.js"></script>
```

I didn't found much information about the error and ways to troubleshoot.